# games-howell test with multiple independent variables

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, post-hoc, heteroscedasticity

my data doesn't meet the homogeneity of variances criterium. After a welch one way test I wanted to perform a post hoc games-howell test since it doesn't require the homogeneity of variances criterium.

my question:

- I have two independent variables, but I can only insert one in the test. Is there a reason you can only insert one? To provide some context, I am researching the effect of precipitation (independent 1) (rain and snowfall) on the rating that reviewers give (dependent). I want to find out if the effect differs for people from certain countries (independent 2). It seems like this is not possible with this test in the following way:

```
oneway(x= data$precipitation * data$segment, y = data$rating, posthoc = 'games-howell')
```

(the ratings range from 1 to 5, precipitation is a dummy variable and there are 3 segments (countries with low, medium and high average precipitation).

- If this doesn't seem like the appropriate analysis, which analysis would be better? (When searching I came across ordinal regression, does this the same or is this something completely else since it also incorporates the ordinal dependent variable?).

Any tips are welcome!

Comment: One-way ANOVA, Welch' F and Kruskal-Wallis tests are appropriate only if you have one numeric and one factor variable with usually more than 2 levels. See details in McDonald's book
http://www.biostathandbook.com/testchoice.html,
http://www.biostathandbook.com/onewayanova.html,
http://www.biostathandbook.com/kruskalwallis.html. At the end of each chapter there are links on how to perform the analyses in R

Answer (score 0):

You could try combining the factors "precipitation" and "segment" into a single variable using the CONCATENATE function in Excel.  This will allow you to test two variables as if they are a single variable.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d